# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Mean app with nginx

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, mean-stack

I have 2 web apps which run on **XX.XX.XX.XX/** and **XX.XX.XX.XX/harvin**, one of them is only node-express and another one is a MEAN stack app respectively. They are configured with **nginx** as below

## nginx.conf

```
# node-express
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

# MEAN app
location /harvin {
        rewrite ^/harvin/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

This question is about the **'Harvin' app (MEAN app)**.
Here is my **app.js** file with [CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) configuration.

## app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const logger = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
var app = express();

var whitelist = ["http://localhost:4200", "XX.XX.XX.XX"];

app.use(
    cors({
        origin(origin, callback) {
            if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
                callback(null, true);
            } else {
                callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
            }
        },
        methods: ["PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"],
        allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With"],
        credentials: true
    })
);

//some middlewares

app.get("/api/login", (req, res) => {
    console.log("login route");
    // login the user
});

// Connect server to Angular 2 Index.html
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
});

//some more routes

module.exports = app;
```

## The problem

The problem I am facing is that when I make any kind of request (like login or signup etc.) on *localhost:8081/api/login* from the client side of **Harvin (MEAN app)** then the console shows **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**.

Even [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) is not logging any kind of login request.

**Exception**  Homepage of Harvin is loading successfully without any error.

## Expected behavior

No **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** in the console when any kind of http request is made from the client side.

## P.S.

This Harvin app is working perfectly on my local machine.

Comment: After several hit and trial attempts, I found out that if I omit "localhost:8081" from the request URL it doesn't complain ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I was serving static files from node with `sendFile` which included some javascript that sent a fetch request to `http://localhost:8081/api` but would always return `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Solved it by setting up a reverse proxy with Nginx exactly the way you did.

Now any fetch request that doesn't have a host in its url is automatically forwarded to the `localhost:8081` socket. So, my requests now fetch from just `/api` which is interpreted as `http://localhost:8081/api`.